# Why assigning sometimes to location.href doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image: screen 1]

On the screen you can see that the script execution has been paused after the line

`newTab.location.href = googlePreviewUrl`
also you can see that despite the usage of `=` operator, value of the `newTab.location.href` is not equal to the `googlePreviewUrl`.

When I have added breakpoint at line 24. And press continute after stop, the assignment is working as expected. See the next screen:

[image: screen 2]

After I have set breakpoints at line 24 few times, script start working as expected. I have tried to use `setTimeout(() => { newTab.location.href = googlePreviewUrl; }, 0);`, but with same result, after reloading the page with clear cache - I have to set breakpoint at line 24, before it is start working, otherwise the `newTab.location.href`is not updated. And I always see:
[image: screen 3]

I have continue to test and found that there are no problems for cases when I'm getting the same token. The token is generated for the file and when I'm opening the same file for the Nth, except first time, I have no problems - I think this is because the token for the same file is being alredy generated.

All the stuff currently looks for me like kind if magic :) Does somebody knows what can go wrong here?

tokenPromise - $http.get(url)

goolePreviewByToken(tokenPromise) - method of the service

The angularjs (angular 1) is being used.

Comment: What happens if you use `newTab.location.assign(googlePreviewUrl)`?